# Python Scraping Product Id using Form Key Data

Tags: python, screen-scraping

Can I  use a Python script in conjunction with an add to cart form key to scrape for product id's by increasing the product id by "1" and reporting back when ID's are found?

The form action takes the form of:

URL/checkout/cart/ajaxadd/uenc/product/**75668**/form_key/123456

The **75668** in the above URL is the product ID that I would like to run through a loop and count up, reporting back ID's as they are found.

Is there a certain resource or any direction that I can be pointed to?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on Stack Overflow. 
For more details see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Thanks has been removed!

Comment: @Skape if you know that all the ID’s are 5 digits (as given here) then you can loop from 10,000 to 99,999.

Comment: Thank you Rishav! As far as beginning this, would loop be the correct way to go back and then is there a resource I can look into for printing results once an active ID has been found?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes, you can do that. But I don't have **public** resource to point you at.